# use of lightning navigate:navigate from one component to another in lightning community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-events, lightningnavigation

```
var eUrl= $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        eUrl.setParams({
            "url": url 
        });
         eUrl.fire();
```

I am trying to replace above in my code as per documentation it is not recommended. I am trying to use lightning:Navigate.

Source component(where buttons are present):-

```
 <aura:component  
    implements= "lightning:isUrlAddressable, force:appHostable, 
   forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
    access="global" controller="ViewNewController"> 
  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
  <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
  <aura:attribute name="url" type="String"/>
 <lightning:button class="PC-save-btn slds-m-right_large" variant="brand" 
    label="edit" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
  </aura:component>
```

controller js

```
   doInit: function(component, event, helper){
      //NAVIGATION USING LIGHTNING
    var navService = component.find("navService");
var pageReference = {

    "type": "standard__component",
    "attributes": {
        "componentName": "c__Reg_Edit"    
    },    
    "state": {
        "c__Id": 'a2R18000004rqUyEAI'  ,// WILL LATER COME AS DYNAMIC
        "c__NORT": 'NORT-99981347'    
    }
  };
component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
var defaultUrl = "#";
navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
.then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
    component.set("v.url", url ? url : defaultUrl);
}), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
    component.set("v.url", defaultUrl);
}));

},
 handleClick: function(component, event, helper) {
var navService = component.find("navService");
// Uses the pageReference definition in the init handler
//JSON.stringify(pageReference); - THIS DATA COMES IN DEBUG JS
//"{"type":"standard__component","attributes": 
//{"componentName":"c__PC_OppReg_Edit"},"state": 
//{"c__Id":"a2R18000004rqUyEAI","c__NORT":"NORT-99981347"}}"
var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");//DEBUG POINT HERE
event.preventDefault();
navService.navigate(pageReference);//CODE IS STUCK HERE
}
```

Component 2:-
 (where needs to be directed to with 2 parameters

```
 <aura:attribute name="res" type="String" />

  <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action=" 
{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
```

CONTROLLER JS

```
onPageReferenceChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    var firstname = myPageRef.state.c__res;
    component.set("v.res", res);
  },
```

Went through following links:-

1. [How to navigate from one lightning component to another Lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135450/how-to-navigate-from-one-lightning-component-to-another-lightning-component)
2. [Help navigating from one lightning page to another in communities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241881/help-navigating-from-one-lightning-page-to-another-in-communities)
3. [Navigating from one salesforce component to another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130281/navigating-from-one-salesforce-component-to-another)
4. https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/

I am getting DEBUG DATA as highligher in comments but .navigate is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

i have found 2 issues in your code.

1. based on your question title, i under stood your issue at in lightning community.if yes

your should use `comm__namedPage` for `type` of pagereference instead of `standard__component`  refer [page reference doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm).

```
function(component, event, helper) {
event.preventDefault();
var navService = component.find("navService");
var pageReference = {
    type: "comm__namedPage",
    attributes: {
        pageName: "some-page-name"
    },
    state: {
        c__myAttr: 'some value'
    }
};
sessionStorage.setItem('pageTransfer', JSON.stringify(pageReference.state));
navService.navigate(pageReference);
}
```

2. why i used session state? 
 i already answered for in other place. please check out this answer [navigate to other page in community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270772/getting-pagereference-is-not-working-in-community/270792#270792)

let me know if you have any issue after this solution applies.